# How to display child pages thumbnail with wp_list_pages on wordpress sidebar?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, sidebar, children

Need help for listing child pages on WordPress sidebar, I have created child pages with Feature Image and its displayed only list with ***wp_list_pages***, But I don't know how to display child pages thumbnail with ***wp_list_pages*** on WordPress sidebar, I can't find an appropriate example of how to use the code to do so. Please help me

Here is my code below:

```
    <?php
        $ancestor_id = 1594;
$descendants = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $ancestor_id ) );
$incl = '';

foreach ( $descendants as $page ) {
    if ( ( $page->post_parent == $ancestor_id )
        || ( $page->post_parent == $post->post_parent )
        || ( $page->post_parent == $post->ID )
    ) {
        $incl .= $page->ID . ",";
    }
}
?>

<ul>
    <?php
    wp_list_pages( array(
        'child_of'    => $ancestor_id,
        'include'     => $incl,
        'link_before' => '',
        'title_li'    => '',
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order'
    ) );
    ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code will display `Featured Image`

```
    <?php
            $ancestor_id = 1594;
    ?>

    <ul>
       <?php
$mypages = get_pages('child_of='.$ancestor_id .'&sort_column=menu_order&parent=0');
if($mypages)
{
echo '<ul>';
foreach($mypages as $page)
{   
?>
<li>
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>
<h2><a href="<?php echo get_page_link($page->ID) ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title ?></a></h2>
</li>
<?php
}
echo '</ul>';
}   
?>
```

Comment: Thank you Raju, I have used your code, but its showing Invalid argument supplied for ***foreach()***

Comment: i think you missed to take `wp_list_pages` in `$mypages`

Comment: i think your `wp_list_pages` is empty please use this above foreach `if (is_array($mypages) || is_object($mypages))
{` and close after `</li>
<?php
}`

Comment: and check or print_r($mypages) and see if it returns anything or blank

Comment: Not working dear, Can you update this on your same code above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182317/discussion-between-raju-eww-and-devbuddy).

Comment: Ok Raju, Thank you